# (nodejs) How can I optimize a kahoot bot joining ridiculously slow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

So, I have a script for a bot to join a kahoot. Each bot takes an average of about 1.5 seconds to join, which seems weirdly long for one simple connection. Running the function without `async` and `await`, which causes it to run much faster but some bots just don't join at all, while running with `await` and `async` causes it to run much slower but all bots join. Is there any way to make this run quickly and still have all bots join?

RESULT WITH ASYNC all bots join, but it takes 1.5s for each and it's slow:
[image]

RESULT WITHOUT ASYNC: all bots "join" within 4 seconds, but on the kahoot only 6 are actually there

```js
bots = [];
var joined = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < process.argv[3]; i++) {
    bots[i] = new Kahoot;
} 

async function runbots(){
    for (let i = 0; i < process.argv[3]; i++) {
        var ktimestart = Date.now()
        await bots[i].join(process.argv[2], randomname(15) + i)
            .then(() => {
                joined++;
                var ktimestop = Date.now()
                log(colors.cyan("Bots Joined: " + joined + "/" + process.argv[3] + " | " + ((joined/process.argv[3]) * 100).toFixed(1) + "%" + " | Last Join Time: " + (ktimestop - ktimestart)/1000 + "s"));
                if (joined == process.argv[3]) {
                    console.log("All Bots Joined!".green);
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                joined--;
            })
    }
};

runbots();
```

Comment: The steps to joining a Kahoot involve multiple steps: fetching and solving a challenge, handshaking with the server, and sending the join packet. This takes time.
In addition, it is likely that Kahoot places limits on the number of connections that can be made at a time from a single location.

Comment: "*some bots just don't join at all*" - what errors are you getting?

Comment: No errors, some bots appear to just not show up with no errors